# explain with reference to bhagavat geeta "why humans feel "I"

Tags: atma, creation, maya, ego, self

With reference   to chapter 7 sloka 6  and   the  commentary  offerred by sri  T.N.Sethumadhavan at esomskruthi.com (a)   the  three divinly  components  viz para, apara prakruthis and the   soul are creations  of  paramatma and  residing inside humans and (b) the   reason for  feeling  of  "I" by  human  appears  to  be the worship  of  apara prakruthi by the  soul ignoring the  para prakruthi.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Sri T.N. Sethumathavan on chapter 7 verse 2-6 of Bhagwad Gita](https://www.esamskriti.com/e/Spirituality/Bhagavad-Gita/Bhagavad-Gita/),
Answer as moderated and summarized by member -

*****Brief Answer***** -

God created humans with three  cosmic entities and  energies viz. Lower entity  called  APARA PRAKRUTHI ie physical world of inert  matter ,visible  or invisible  ,Higher entity  called  PARA PRAKRUTHI is Consciousness which  is eternal and dynamic and third  is    himself   as  Jeevatma. All   the  creation   has  the  three ingredients of which the  first  two are of  varying proportions. The  objective  of  creation  might  be that Jeevatma to  identify with PARA PRAKRUTHI and accordingly use APARA PRAKRUTHI and attain  Moksha. But in  the  process, if Jeevatma ignores PARA PRAKRUTHI and start  using APARA PRAKRUTHI ,  it  will  lead  to EGO and feeling  of  I by  which  Jeevatma forgets  the  truth of its  belonging  to GOD and falsely identified separately by  I and  looses  its spiritual permanent happiness and becomes temporary inert  nature and  takes  all   sufferings  of  matter.

**Elaborate answer**

These type of questions requires minimum understanding about creation and creator as first step. Knowledge of God and experiencing God are two different aspects and God is the cause of the appearance of the universe and all things in it. He is the essence, substance and substratum of everything, whether visible or invisible.

**CREATION**

The word Creation, only refers to the manifestation of something which was potentially, manifestly existent. Nothing in the creation is non existent. The unmanifest matter later may becomes manifest, which means it is available for transaction. An analogy is that of butter which is known to be preexisting in manifested form in milk will become manifested as butter on churning the milk. The Lord proceeds to explain his manifestations as the universe and the power behind it. He speaks of these manifestations as His lower and higher Prakriti. It is to say that both prakriti existed in causal form before creation and manifestation and combination of these two ingredients causes things to be born and function.

**APARA PRAKRUTHI**

lower Prakriti called APARA Prakrit is eight folds and made up of the five elements Earth, water, fire, air, ether and mind, ego and intellect. The  matter is the source of all forms of energy and is referred as Beejam or Maya. Also it will  be  always  changing  from   one  form  to  other and  its  state  is  temporary. It  needs  no  further explanation.

**PARA PRAKRUTHI**

But  the other HIGHER  Prakruthi needs   elaborate  explanation. The Self has, besides elements of APARA Prakrit , equipments of a higher nature which are Pure Consciousness or Awareness i.e. PARA Prakrit.The higher Prakriti called PARA Prakrit is having several names like Vignana , Consciousness or Awareness .Its cosmic  energy  levels  are  much  much  higher  than APARA PRAKRUTHI. It  never  changes  and  permanent  in  nature.  It is this spiritual aspect in everybody that makes it possible for the body, mind  ,intellect and ego which are inert matters to function as if they are very cognizant and intelligent. The spiritual factor is the entity with whose contact the body equipment works and without which it becomes dull and insentient. Without this spiritual spark ,man will be no more than a stone, and he will not be able to experience the world outside or within him.  The world of objects, the world of feelings and the world of ideas that we experience constitute in their totality the Jagat or universe which is supported by the principle of consciousness. Consciousness is   non-material entity . It does not come under matter and therefore it does not come within time and space. This means that as consciousness is beyond time and space it has to be eternal which implies that before the creation, consciousness also existed.

**ATMA**

In  addition   to  the  above  two PRAKRUTHIES , there  is  a  third entity , God  himself resides within  all  creation  as  JEEVATMA. At the Micro level i.e., with reference to an individual, it  is given the name of Atma. The very same at the Macro level is called Brahman. Therefore Atma and Brahman are synonymous meaning the same thing .

Once the individual understands the distinction between matter and Atma , he will know that the cause of all our sufferings is due to Atma identifying with matter.  When Atma  is detached from all its identifications with matter, it rediscovers for itself its own essential nature as Perfection and Bliss Absolute.

**EGO**

The Atma  identifying with matter or apara Prakrit is called ego. This is also called super imposition on the Truth through ignorance.  It is apara Prakrit by which the atma gets bound with EGO.  It is the ego that rediscovers itself to be nothing other than the spirit or para Prakrit that presides over the matter. The process of such rediscovery of truth by EGO is very interesting. Let us understand the entire process of formation of EGO and rediscovery of truth.

**PROCESS OF  FEELING  OF  I**

The five elements of matter are represented by the sense-organs by which the individual lives and gathers experiences in the world of sense objects. The sense organs are the channels through which the information stimuli reaches the mind. The impulses received in the mind are classified and systematized as knowledge by the intellect.  Mind also memorizes the large amount of data about the matter.  However, there may be differences in perception and efficiency of conduct of entire process among the individuals that lead to another quality referred as Intellectuality among humans and humans are classified with clever, intelligent, genius , innocent ,foolish etc. These assimilations bring another quality EGO among humans and during all these assimilations the spirit falsely identifies the body with the ego and the sense of `I' or` My' is produced.

**BOTH  PRAKRITI ARE ESSENTIAL**

The above mentioned higher and lower natures together cause the manifestation of the world of plurality.  If there is no matter, the latent dynamic energy of the Spirit will not have a field for its expression.  The matter by itself is dormant and it cannot function unless the Spirit is there to activate it, to enliven it. An example of this principle is electricity and the bulb.  The bulb is the inert matter and the electricity is the dynamic spirit. It is obvious that one is of no use without the other. When the spirit functions through the five layers of the matter it finds a place to express itself.

**CONCLUSON**

The combination of the higher and lower natures (Prakrit) is the womb of all beings i.e., these two are the cause for the origin of all creatures or manifestation.  The lower nature manifests itself as the material body and the higher nature as the enlivening soul, the experiencer.

Thanks for reading,
with  great regards'
user 26043

Comment: Namaste welcome to HSE. While on the site, you can go through the [help centre](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) as well as [Guidelines for new users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). The rules insist on deriving the answer based on scriptures or great acharyas. Also asking a Q only for self-answering; and repeated edits are not considered very respectable. Hope you have a good time on the site :)

Comment: Thanks. The  reply  was  taken  from the  findings of  a   researcher  who  was   listed   and  authenticated  by  similar site. Please clarify whether permitted. I  understood self  answering allowed on  site. please  clarify. I waited  72 hours  before  publishing to   check for  some  other  answer.  I  thought ,  my  answer will  create some interest on  question so  that some  review   will  be  done  on  my  answer. Regret very  much for repeated  edits.  I  will  improve my work. Your review is  of  great  help to  me . Highly  appreciated. Once  again  thanking  you.- venkata